# Add database table from website

Tags: php, sql, create-table

**EDIT:Well I guess I should asked then before this question, would it be better to have a database full of tables(college names) that stores numbers than can be sorted in ascending order, or have a database with one table and select all the rows with the same "college name" and then sort the data from those rows after?**

"
Is it possible to add a table in a database like...

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
column_name1 data_type,
column_name2 data_type,
column_name3 data_type,
....
)
```

...but call from a webpage instead of adding a table through mysql? So make a table in a database from code on my website?"

Comment: yes, of course, execute any valid sql statment against the RDBMS from a PHP script (or other languaje) and you will get the result there

Comment: Possible … but almost never a good idea. Most of the time people asking these questions should be making the value of `table_name` the value of an extra column in an existing table.

Comment: Don't add or modify tables programmatically. Find a way to structure your data that lets you put all the data in one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can send SQL queries through PHP.

Here is a resource that shows just what you're looking for I think
[PHP MySQL Create Database and Tables](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create.asp)

**edit:**

It depends on what you're doing, but I agree with the above comments that creating a table on page view is in most cases the wrong move.

If they all have the same basic structure I would put them all in the same table, and you can index the "college name" column.  Reading from the database even with many many rows will still be quick, and if you decide to change something later you won't have to change X amount of tables.

You can also retrieve sorted results

```
SELECT * FROM Colleges WHERE name = 'University of Wisconsin' ORDER BY student_count ASC
```